# Python Challenge- #3: it prints random letters instead of 7

Tags: python

```
import re

b=re.findall('[A-Z]+[a-z]+[A-Z]',k)

for i in b:
    print (i)
```

I have written this code. The string in k is too long to print here.
 I need to find all sets of sub strings where the middle later is in lower case and three letters exactly on each side is upper case. 
I think this code should work. But, its printing random number of letters in each substring .
What is the problem in my code or how can I fix it ?
Please help!

Comment: Well, right now you're only checking if one letter on each side is uppercase, not 3.

Comment: Well actually an arbitrary number of letters > 1 on the left side, and 1 letter on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexp shouldn't contain `+`, which matches 1 or more uppercase letters. If you need to get something like `AAAbCCC` just try:

```
b=re.findall('[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}',k)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its not the full code. But it set me on the right path